# How to get a line number when parsing with QXmlDefaultHandler?

Tags: qt

I am parsing a xml file with QXmlDefaultHandler like this:

```
void Parser::ParseFilename(const char* pFilename)
{
  LOG_DEBUG("Parser::ParseFilename(%s)", pFilename);
  ClearState();

  m_inputFile.setFileName(pFilename);
  QXmlInputSource source( &m_inputFile );
  QXmlSimpleReader reader;

  reader.setContentHandler( this );
  reader.parse( source );
}
```

I need to know line numbers for error messages. How can I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself.

I was not completely clear in my question because I didn't write that I need to generate my own custom error messages. For example I need to make complicate validations of certain attributes. Then, if the attribute is invalid, I need to write message like: "Error on line 15454 column 48, attritubute 'number' should be a prime number but is 65536'.

The approach suggested by Ariya Hidayat works only for messages generated by the SAX parser itself (like malformed XML).

For custom messages I need to overload   `setDocumentLocator ( QXmlLocator * locator )` which tells me about the current locator, and  save somewhere the value of the locator like `savedLocator = locator;`  Actual line number is obtained by `locator->lineNumber().`

Answer (score 1):

Use the exception that is passed to [QXmlErrorHandler::error()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qxmlerrorhandler.html#error) function. You can set a custom error handler using [QXmlReader::setErrorHandler()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qxmlreader.html#setErrorHandler).